# unit testing response status code in spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to unit test the following method in controller

```
  @ExceptionHandler(ExceptionName.class)
  @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  public String handleIOException(ExceptionName ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "errors.messagepage";
  }
```

I can test for the returned view name.

I also want to test for the Response Status code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, not as a unit test. The annotation is an instruction to the framework, and isn't part of your executable code.

The only way to test this is to bootstrap a `DispatcherServlet` as part of your test (an integration test, really), or to deploy the application and test it over HTTP.

If you really want to do this in a unit test, then consider setting the response code on the `HttpServletResponse` manually, rather than using an annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ExceptionName.class)
public String handleIOException(ExceptionName ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  response.setStatus(500)
  return "errors.messagepage";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at following blog.

[Spring MVC: Integration Testing Controllers](http://tedyoung.me/2011/02/14/spring-mvc-integration-testing-controllers/)

It details setting up a mock servlet context and WebApplicationContext from within JUnit. Using this setup I am able to test Response Code set using annotation on the controller methods.

Comment: This works for testing url mapping to functions. But, how to create a MockHttpRequest that throws exception? If you see the code in the question, its a Exception handler and not a URL handler. ie. MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("POST", "/") doesnt work for me. my request is neither a POST on some URL nor a GET. Its a handler for any url which throws Exception

Comment: It should work. You need to simulate the exception handler. The exception handler for ExceptionName.class in your example will get executed if this exception gets thrown when the controller that is processing your request throws this exception. So, the key is to execute request for a path mapped in your controller and send some data in your request that causes this exception to be thrown. I am using this setup in my current project and it works like a charm and lets me test controller response, exception handlers, http response codes.